OpenJ9 GC cause "collect due to scavanger percolate"
For this gc cause "max end of major GC (collect due to scavanger percolate)", I can't find any documentation about this reason. What does that mean?
For OpenJ9. We have frequent GCS and use the SOA area. Gc strategy is gencon.
gc cause image

For GC policy Gencon, at the time Local GC (Scavenge) should be performed, there is number of cases when Global GC can be executed ("percolated") instead. It might be low space or high fragmentation level for Tenure, Classes unloading threshold reached, JNI Critical section has been opened in the Nursery etc. If you need deeper description you can find us at openj9.slack.com.
